# iOS Touch Icon through XLSX file?

Tags: php, html, ipad, icon, apple

I'm setting up some iPads, and pointing Safari to `www.mywebsite.com/spreadsheet.xlsx` and it's displaying the document fine. That part is OK.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to add a iOS Icon to the document so I can save it to the springboard of the iPad? Maybe embedding the document in HTML?

PHP could also possibly be used but I'm really not sure how I would go about doing this, has anyone managed anything like this before?

Answer (score 1):

You probably know [How to Add Home Screen Icons in Safari for the iPad](http://browsers.about.com/od/howtousemobilebrowser1/ss/Add-Home-Screen-Icons-Safari-Ipad_5.htm). What I can't verify right now is if you can add a link to a specific non-html document the same way, but if not, linking to an HTML page that gives a note and redirects automatically after some seconds to the document to initiate the download might work.

Like with:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=www.mywebsite.com/spreadsheet.xlsx" />
```

Comment: Interesting way to do it. I'll have a look and let you know. Thankyou.